# learning guarantees for gaussian weighting of training points

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric, rbf-kernel

I have my training data for binary classification that consists of $N$ pairs $$(x_i\in R^F, y_i \in {-1, 1})$$ $i\in [1,\dots,N]$. My classification rule of a new point $x$ is simply

$$
\hat{y}(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & 0 < \frac{\sum_i y_i\phi(|x_i-x|/r)}{\sum_i \phi(|x_i - x|/r)} \\\\
-1 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$
where $\phi(z) = \exp(-z^2/2)$ and $r = \alpha N^{\frac {1} {2F}} $.

I'm unable to find any reference regarding learning guarantees, even if this seems a pretty standard approach.

Bishop writes

> It can be shown that both the K-nearest-neighbour
> density estimator and the kernel density estimator converge to the true probability
> density in the limit N → ∞ provided V shrinks suitably with N, and K grows with
> N (Duda and Hart, 1973).

but this is for density estimation and I couldn't find the reference.